# How to sent path Control to choose folder prompted value?

Tags: cocoa, applescript, applescript-objc

I am trying to make a small application using ApllescriptObjC, and I could not figure out how to get to show the the folder path on the Path control,  "pathPanel" is the outlet connected to path colntrol
thanks

```
on selectFolder:sender

set PRJpath to (choose folder)

pathPanel's setURL(PRJpath)
```

end selectFolder:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types don't match.

- `choose folder` returns an AppleScript `alias` specifier.
- The parameter of `setURL` is supposed to be a Cocoa `NSURL` instance.

To make `NSURL` from `alias` specifier first get the `POSIX path` string of the `alias`.

```
set PRJpath to POSIX path (choose folder)
```

Then create the url

```
pathPanel's setURL:(current application's NSURL's fileURLWithPath:PRJpath)
```